# Scala: Case class unapply vs a manual implementation and type erasure

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-erasure, case-class, unapply

I'm trying to understand what Scala does with Case Classes that makes them somehow immune to type erasure warnings.

Let's say we have the following, simple class structure. It's basically an `Either`:

```scala
abstract class BlackOrWhite[A, B]

case class Black[A,B]( val left: A ) extends BlackOrWhite[A,B]

case class White[A,B]( val right: B ) extends BlackOrWhite[A,B]
```

And you're trying to use it like this:

```scala
object Main extends App {

    def echo[A,B] ( input: BlackOrWhite[A,B] ) = input match {
        case Black(left) => println( "Black: " + left )
        case White(right) => println( "White: " + right )
    }

    echo( Black[String, Int]( "String!" ) )
    echo( White[String, Int]( 1234 ) )
}
```

Everything compiles and runs without any problems. However, when I try implementing the `unapply` method myself, the compiler throws a warning. I used the following class structure with the same `Main` class above:

```scala
abstract class BlackOrWhite[A, B]

case class Black[A,B]( val left: A ) extends BlackOrWhite[A,B]

object White {

    def apply[A,B]( right: B ): White[A,B] = new White[A,B](right)

    def unapply[B]( value: White[_,B] ): Option[B] = Some( value.right )

}

class White[A,B]( val right: B ) extends BlackOrWhite[A,B]
```

Compiling that with the `-unchecked` flag issues the following warning:

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to target/scala-2.9.1.final/classes...
[warn] src/main/scala/Test.scala:41: non variable type-argument B in type pattern main.scala.White[_, B] is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
[warn]         case White(right) => println( "White: " + right )
[warn]                   ^
[warn] one warning found
[info] Running main.scala.Main
```

Now, I understand type erasure and I've tried to get around the warning with `Manifests` (to no avail so far), but what is the difference between the two implementations? Are case classes doing something that I need to add in? Can this be circumvented with `Manifests`?

I even tried running the case class implementation through the scala compiler with the `-Xprint:typer` flag turned on, but the `unapply` method looks pretty much like I expected:

```
case <synthetic> def unapply[A >: Nothing <: Any, B >: Nothing <: Any](x$0: $iw.$iw.White[A,B]): Option[B] = if (x$0.==(null))
    scala.this.None
else
    scala.Some.apply[B](x$0.right);
```

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Scala?  I can't reproduce your issue, and this related question from a few months ago determined a similar issue to yours as being a compiler bug.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008428/difference-between-home-made-extractor-and-case-class-extractor

Comment: I'm using 2.9.1.final (On Xubuntu 11.10, if it matters)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I cannot give a complete answer, but I can tell you that even though the compiler generates an `unapply` method for case classes, when it pattern matches on a case class it does not use that unapply method. If you try `-Ybrowse:typer` using both builtin case matching and your `unapply` method, you will see a very different syntax tree is produced (for the `match`) depending on which is used. You can also browse the later phases and see that the difference remains.

Why Scala does not use the builtin unapply I am not sure, though it may be for the reason you bring up. And how to get around it for your own `unapply` I have no idea. But this is the reason Scala seems to magically avoid the problem.

After experimenting, apparently this version of `unapply` works, though I'm a bit confused about why:

```
def unapply[A,B](value: BlackOrWhite[A,B]): Option[B] = value match {
    case w: White[_,_] => Some(w.right)
    case _ => None
}
```

The difficulty with your `unapply` is that somehow the compiler has to be convinced that if a `White[A,B]` extends a `BlackOrWhite[C,D]` then `B` is the same as `D`, which apparently the compiler is able to figure out in this version but not in yours. Not sure why.

Comment: Actually, `unapply` was created so the user could replicate the functionality that `case class` provided. There are a few other places where the official explanation for how things work is not how the compiler actually do it.

Answer (score 6):

I can't give you the answer on the difference between case class match and unapply. However in their book (Odersky, Spoon, Venners) "Programming in Scala" 2nd chptr 26.6 "Extractors versus case classes" they write:

> "they (case classes) usually lead to more efficient pattern matches
>   than extractors, because the Scala compiler can optimize patterns over
>   case classes much better than patterns over extractors. This is
>   because the mechanisms of case classes are fixed, whereas an unapply
>   or unapplySeq method in an extractor could do almost anything. Third,
>   if your case classes inherit from a sealed base class, the Scala
>   compiler will check our pattern matches for exhaustiveness and will
>   complain if some combination of possible values is not covered by a
>   pattern. No such exhaustiveness checks are available for extractors."

Which says to me that the two are more different than one would expect at first glance, however without being specific on what the exact differences are.